# Add a Calculated Row For Custom Subtotaling

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to perform custom subtotaling on sales data to give a total for US and Non-US sales offices. My worksheet looks like the table labeled "current" and I am trying to make it look like the table labeled "desired result"

When I tried to group the sales centers as US and Non US the pill (dimension) was greyed out. After googling through a bunch of threads I found that grouping was not supported for secondary data sources. Is there anyway to do a manual calculation in the table calculations to add a row or do custom subtotaling?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use a secondary data source or could you use a cross-database join instead? That would allow you to create the grouping you need and see a subtotal.

Comment: I found a workaround for the grouping [here](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-groups-using-calculated-fields) but I'm still having difficulty getting subtotals based on the grouping. When I got to analysis>totals>add all subtotals a message displays "Subtotals of discrete measures are not supports. Disabling subtotals on 'Year'. The grouping is a measure

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for the country (assuming that you have the country in your data)
 [see my example I had states and zip codes]

[image]

Then go to analysis > totals > check on **show grand total** and on **add all subtotals**

Visit [Calculations totals - Grand total turn on](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_totals_grandtotal_turnon.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There are no higher level geo identifiers in the data source just a city name and unique city identifier number. If country was available it would subtotal by country but I would still have issues getting the subtotal of non-us where there are multiple countries (subtotal for us, china, spain, etc) I found a workaround for the grouping here but I'm still having difficulty getting subtotals based on the grouping. When I got to analysis>totals>add all subtotals a message displays "Subtotals of discrete measures are not supports. Disabling subtotals on 'Year'